# Need to replace all the null values with '0' in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a vertica table, "CUSTOMER" which contains around 10 columns. Each column contains few null values. So I have to write one query which will replace all the null values to '0'.

Is it possible to do it in vertica. Can anyone please help me on that.

Comment: _Replace_, do you mean in the result from a select, or the actual table values?

Comment: NULL values make sense, they shouldn't just be replaced.

Comment: either of it is fine

Comment: `coalesce(column, '0')` will return the column value if non-null, othwise '0'.

Comment: Thank you. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(col1, 0) as col1, . . . 
from t;
```

You can incorporate similar logic into an `update` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In a `SELECT`, as @GordonLinoff says, you use `COALESCE()`, or the slightly faster `NVL()`, `IFNULL()` or `ISNULL()` functions (they are all synonyms of each other and take exactly two arguments, while `COALESCE()` is more flexible - at a cost -  with a variable-length argument list, returning the first non-null value of a list of arguments of varying length).

For updating, strive to update only the rows you need to update, and go, for each column:

`UPDATE t SET col1=0 WHERE col1 IS NULL;`
`UPDATE t SET col2=0 WHERE col2 IS NULL;`

Well, in an extreme case, you might end up updating the same row as often as its number of columns, then you have won nothing - but it's worth planning to minimise how often you update.

Or, you might consider:

```
UPDATE t SET
  col1 = NVL(col1,0)
, col2 = NVL(col2,0)
, col3 = NVL(col3,0)
[...]
WHERE col1 IS NULL
   OR col2 IS NULL
   OR col3 IS NULL
[...]
;
```

Being columnar, and due to the fact that each UPDATE, in Vertica, is a DELETE and an INSERT anyway, it makes no difference if you update just one column or all columns.